# Cron automation run perl program not working?

Tags: perl, cron

I just write perl program for automation purpose using cron

my cron is

```
*/30 * * * * perl /path/to/cron.pl
```

cron.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

`/usr/bin/perl /path/to/run.pl`;
```

Inside the code I run other perl program using back tick.

run.pl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(FL,">text.txt") or die $!;

print FL "hi";

close FL;
```

Whenever I run cron.pl it has created "text.txt" file. But the cron run the program cron.pl is running but run.pl has not run. Can any one tell me what I did wrong in code?

Comment: Mandatory comment: always put `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the top of every Perl script. Your problem is probably due to using relative path when calling `run.pl`. Try using absolute path to Perl interpreter and the script: `/usr/bin/perl /absolute/path/to/run.pl`;

Comment: @bart thanks for your comment . I am using use strict and use warning then i added absolute path in that program but still it's not working.

Comment: How do know run.pl is not being executed?  That script is opening the filehandle in read mode, but the next line is trying to write to it, which is not going to work.

Comment: We can't tell you what's wrong with your code, without your actual code. But likely `perl run.pl` is missing a path.

Comment: Do you know what the current directory is when `run.pl` is called when called from cron? Are you looking for the file there? Do you have writing permissions in that directory? Did you try to set an absolute path to the target file like `/tmp/test.txt`, where you are sure that you can write it?

Comment: If there is no any errors you do not use 'warnings' and 'strict'. Try to find any error messages

Comment: Running cronjobs is always a mess because they have such a limited environment (compared to regular login shells). Try `*/30 * * * * perl /path/to/cron.pl 1>/tmp/stdout.txt 2>/tmp/stderr.txt` and inspect the two files for errors.

Comment: @Ron Bergin This is sample program so forgot to put write mode in this sample program anyway i put into my original program still it's not working

Comment: modify your cron command to also use the full path for perl

Comment: @Tutor cron.pl run successfully but second program run.pl is not calling anyway that also i tried to but not working

Comment: Giving us "samples" which doesn't represent what you've got, means it's impossible to diagnose. It's really important that if you _don't_ give use the actual code that you've got the problem with, you give us an example that you have actually tried, and that works, and we can use to reproduce the problem. Cutting it back to a minimum is fine, and indeed desirable. Just makes sure the sample presents the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `cron` line have to contain a full path to the executable!

```
*/30 * * * * /usr/bin/perl /path/to/cron.pl
```